# How to hide action method in url mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to hide action method name in url but no case. i have this:

RouteConfig:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "People",
            url: "People/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "People", action = "Index"}
        )
```

PeopleController:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
```

And i have to call this method using Url.Action("Index","People",new{id="test"}) or same in the browser put http:www.mysite.com/People/test

no like this: http:www.mysite.com/People/Index/test

Any idea? Thanks

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "People",
            url: "People/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "People", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you are hiding the action method. Your routing engine is doing what it appears that you're asking. Why do you want to hide the Action, but still have it appear in your URL?

Comment: Check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#optionals-and-defaults

Comment: I have to hide the action method in the url: "http:www.mysite.com/People/Index/test"
want change to 
"http:www.mysite.com/People/test"

Comment: can you please post all your RouteConfig class ?

Comment: Route ordering matters. Also, if you had used the [Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/), you would have found the problem instantly. Also, if you had used the Google, you would have found the Route Debugger instantly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your "People" route above your "Default". The `People/test` is getting caught by the definition of the "Default", and never getting down to the "People" one. Like Exceptions in a string of catch blocks, your route mapping needs to start at most specific, and work their way to more general.

Comment: Really thanks, now it seems stupid question but i didn't find solution in days

Comment: There's a reason why the Routing Engine is at least an entire chapter in the good MVC books.